# ScrollToIndex out of range : requested index NaN but maximum is 3 -- SwiperFlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

this is my swiperflatlist component in which i am rendering the images from api but why i am getting this error i coundn't understand pls let me know why i am getting this error?

index nan should but the components are called as map of flatlist ?

```
    <SwiperFlatList
      autoplayDelay={2}
      autoplay
       autoplayLoop
      index={0}
    data={this.state.achhamall}
    renderItem={({item}) => // Standard Image
                   <View style={[styles.child, {  }]}>


             <Image
                  style={{height:400, width: width , resizeMode:'contain'}}
                  source={{uri: item.image}}
                />
                </View>
                    }
    showPagination
  />
```

Comment: you have rendered only one component, try to add two view inside swiper

Comment: i didn't get u ? two view...